# sharing url link of a website that renders the logo of the site on facebook

Tags: facebook

Hi I have these meta tags. When I share this url on facebook the logo of the website is displayed. My problem is when I shared the url link on facebook, the blog url image is not rendered properly but it displays the logo of the website. Which is wrong. Here is my meta tag

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />

    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

    <meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/400dpiLogo.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="test test test tesdt" />



<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags BEGIN -->
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:pageName.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
        <meta expr:content='data:pageName.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
    </b:if>
    <!-- Open Graph Meta Tags END -->
```

Can someone please help me fix this thing? I've been doing many changes but no good. I used the facebook debugger on it. Any help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Give us an actual example URL where we can see the problem.

Comment: http://www.nannyshareaustralia.com.au this one and this one
http://www.nannyshareaustralia.com.au/blog/view-details/how-much-should-i-pay-my-babysitter
share this links into your facebook just to test

Comment: Share dialog preview shows http://www.nannyshareaustralia.com.au/assets/images/400dpiLogo.png as image for both of them, as specified.

Comment: yes.. that is my problem how to change that?

Comment: Well if you want a different image, then specify a different image in the `og:image` meta tag 
…?

Comment: so you mean i will add another one og:image?

Comment: Why _another_? I thought the one that gets displayed now is one you _don’t_ want?

Comment: cause the og:image im using is that when i shared the blog in facebook the logo of the site will render which is wrong

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say here. Just put the URL of the image you _want_ to be used when sharing as `og:image`.

Comment: yes i just did the og:image in the logo for the site but when sharing blog url still logo of the site is getting

Comment: If you _specify_ the log as `og:image`, then that is what you _get_ when sharing … (If you updated the `og:image` tag to some other image, then put the page through the debug tool again, to clear Facebook’s cache.)